# How to recover data on a phone stuck in boot?

Tags: adb, recovery-mode, data-recovery, boot-loop, xiaomi

I know it is a common question.
But I have been browsing the internet for the past 2 days and I can't find the answer to my specific case.
So, I have a Redmi Note 5 pro Indian model. But for the past 2 days, It has been stuck on booting up.
I can enter Fastboot( Vol down+Power button), But I can't enter Recovery mode.
The phone is stuck on Mi logo. Even when I enter the Fastboot, It is stuck on the Fastboot logo. 
I have tried all the key combos.I have also let the phone discharge completely (The screen turns off and notification light blinks) and charge a bit before trying to boot it up. I also have ADB in my laptop. I have USB DEBUGGING ENABLED on the phone, But bootloader is locked(Never played with flashing and all).
I tried connecting the phone to the laptop too, But ADB doesn't recognize the device. I believe for the device to be recognized, It has to boot up atleast?
Anyway, I really want to recover my data from the internal storage of the phone. Is there anyway I can do this? Please help.

Comment: Hello. What are you hoping to achieve by booting into recovery mode? Stock Recovery doesn't provide access to Internal storage through adb. And a custom recovery cannot be booted into unless bootloader is unlocked. Is the data you are after not synced to your Google account (Contacts and Photos especially)?

Comment: @Firelord Hey, I had read that I could try clearing the cache and try to reboot. The photos and contacts are synced. However, I have been writing and maintaining a personal diary for the past 3 years. It has some precious memories,entries along with some photos. This is NOT Synced. This is the only data that I really don't want to lose. Is there any way of like maybe reinstalling the OS or something(Similar to what we do on Windows) without losing the app data?